# WMS service transformation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, coordinate-system

I'm trying to understand the relation between QGIS and WMS services. I request for a WMS service (declared coordinate system : CGRS_93_LTM) via QGIS software in WGS84 coordinate reference system. Which software is responsible for service transformation from CGRS_93_LTM to WGS84? 
As i know, the server provide the dataset with the reference system and a boundary box (min, max coordinates for X,Y axes). So, QGIS define the boundary box of the dataset in CGRS_93, and then transform it to WGS84?

Answer (score 3):

> Which software is responsible for service transformation from CGRS_93_LTM to WGS84?

If the GetCapabilities response for the WMS service reports that it supports your WGS84 CRS (I assume you mean [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326)) then you can request it directly from the WMS service.  If on the other hand the service does not support this CRS you can use the on the fly CRS transformation.  In this situation it is QGIS that does the reprojection.

Comment: So, if server database is compatible with the coordinate reference system that i want is responsible for the transformation? Futhermore, if it does not exist Qgis does the transformation?

Comment: No, it's the software (ArcGIS, MapServer, GeoServer, deegree, ...) that provides the WMS service that does the transformation, not the database server. The service provider (the person who sets up the WMS service) decides which projections their service will support and those available projections are listed in the service capabilities response.

Comment: I got some intuition about the relation between the softwares. Futhermore, if server support the capability providing the coordinate reference system that i want, is the main responsible of the transformation? In the other hand, if the coordinate reference system is not list in the service capabilities, GIS software does the transformation?

Comment: It's not so much if the server software supports the ability to do a transformation, but if the service provider enables the projection to be served.  A GIS client such as QGIS is not allowed to request a projection from a WMS if the server doesn't advertise that projection as part of the that service (according to the specification).  In such a situation the only possibility is to request one of the supported projections from the service and reproject the image in your client.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS set your Project (menu)>Project Properties>CRS tab to WGS84 (4326) and check the box that says Enable on the fly CRS transformation.  Then you can make a WMS connection to your server and add in the layer.  The layer will be reprojected on the fly once adding into QGIS to align with WGS84 GCS.